# (Notepad++) Find strings above a certain length between two substrings

Tags: notepad++

Does anyone know if there is a way to find any text that is longer than a certain length, and is between 2 substrings?

For example:

```
<element><![CDATA[Hi, I'm a message.]]></element>
```

I need to find any text string within CDATA[ ] exceeds 136 characters.
The string may also be on multiple lines:

```
<element><![CDATA[Hi, I'm a message,
and I'm on 2 lines.]]></element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following search with Search Mode `Regular expression` and `. matches newline` selected

```
<\!\[CDATA\[(?:(?!\]\]>).){137,}
```

Explanation:
`<\!\[CDATA\[` is a literal, with escaping, for the start of the CDATA tag

`(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group and is logical bracketing here

`(?!\]\]>).` says so long as there isn't a literal `]]>` here match any character

`{137,}` says do that 137 times (at least)

Thus this will hit any `CDATA` of the size you want

You may want to add a `\]\]>` at the end to eat the close tags, however matching the closing tag isn't necessary (assuming well formed document)

This will count new lines as characters, if that's a problem you can replace `.` with `(?:.\n*)` to  reduce this effect

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the explanation.
it didn't quite do the trick, the complete search string gets 0 results.

"<\!\[CDATA\[" on it's own finds that part of the string, and "(?:(?!\]\]>).)" on it's own finds any character except the closing square bracket of CDATA[], but putting those together gets 0 results

Comment: I figured it out with the help of your search string! I had to put the "." at the beginning of "(?:(?!\]\]>).)" to get this: `<\!\[CDATA\[(?:.(?!\]\]>)){137,}`. Thanks for such a well explained answer that someone with no knowledge of notepad++ search terms was able to figure it out!